# PHP Login script only works with usernames known to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

This script should get some Variables of a submit form. Then it should check them from the DB and see if password and username match, if not it should send them back to the login page.

I already tried letting it check if the username exist via:

```
$this = "Select name from user where name = '".$_POST['name']"'";

$query = mysqli_query($conn,$this);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

if (empty($row['name']){

 do this;

}

}
```

But still got a blank page.

```
<?php
include "private/dbconnection.inc.php";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if(!$conn){
  die ("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$selectpw = "SELECT * from user where name = '".$_POST['name']." ' ";
$pwcheck = mysqli_query($conn,$selectpw);
$selectname = "SELECT name from user where name = '".$_POST['name']."'";
$namecheck = mysqli_query($conn,$selectname);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pwcheck)){
  if ( $_POST['password'] === $row['password'] && $_POST['name'] === $row['name'] ){
header("Location:https://myhost.de/xxx/this/user.php");
}
else{
  header("Location:https://myhost.de/xxxx/prototyp1/");
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The script should check if the user is valid for login if hes not he should be send back to login. If hes valid he gets to another page.

But it only works with usernames the mysql knows with other usernames im stuck on the php page and it just shows a blank screen.

Comment: Please be aware that your code is **vulnerable** to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). **Never** use `$_POST` directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding to variables. Also ensure that your database user only has the [**required privileges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: "But it only works with usernames the mysql knows" that's usually how a login system should work?

Comment: yes but i want it to redirect me to another page if it doesnt know the username and he doesnt do that

Comment: after `Location:` there should be s space before the URI

Comment: So you're storing plaintext passwords in your database, huh?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As Obsidian said, your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection, therefore it would be more suitable to use PDO. This can be achieve like so in the basic code example below.

```php
<?php
include "private/dbconnection.inc.php";

try {
    $db = new PDO('host=' . $server_name . ';dbname=' . $database . 'charset=utf-8;', $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    throw $e; // Throw the PDOException if something failed
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['username'] && !empty($_POST['username'])
    {
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?');

        $query->bindParam(1, trim($_POST['username']));

        if($query->execute())
        {
            $password = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($_POST['password'] == $password)
            {
                header('Location: https://myhost.de/xxx/this/user.php');
            } else {
                header('Location: https://myhost.de/xxxx/prototyp1/');
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I just want to say that this example is very basic and does not handle all of the validation and errors as it should.